# Jquery Ajax Server Polling; Polling the server based on an earlier ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

What I am trying to do:
1. Initially gives an ajax request to the server based on some inputs
2. The server returns a job id generated by RQ (Python-rq)
3. Based on the job id ajax request made to a url constructed with the jobid regularly till a valid response is obtained

What I have:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/start",
    data:{crop: valueCrop, state: valueState, variablemeasure: valueVariable, unit:unitMeasure, from:yearFrom, to:yearTo},
    success: function(results) {
        console.log(results);
        var jobId='';
        jobId = results;
        function ajax_request() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/results/" + jobId,
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(xhr_data) {
                    if (xhr_data == {"status":"pending","data":[]}){
                        console.log("Waiting for response");
                        setTimeout(function() { ajax_request(); }, 2000);   
                    } else {
                        console.log(xhr_data);
                    }
                },
                error:function(error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }       
            });
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }       
})
```

Is this even possible? I am not getting any output at all on the console although the rq says the job is finished. I think it is not entering that if loop. When I visit the "/results/jobId" url I am able to see the result.
Please help.

Comment: I am able to see the job id in the console. Then nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few bugs in this code. First of all, you have defined the function `ajax_request()`. But you are not calling it. You can call it at the end of its definition.

Secondly, this code is problematic:

```
if (xhr_data == {"status":"pending","data":[]})
```

The object notation creates another object which is definitely not equal to `xhr_data`.

You can do:

```
if (xhr_data.status === "pending")
```

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I fixed it just now myself. You pointed out the main bugs. Thanks a lot for your effort.